# Share SSH keys with VS Code Devcontainer running with Docker's WSL2 backend

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm reading [these docs on sharing SSH keys with a dev container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_using-ssh-keys), but I can't get it to work.

My setup is as follows:

- Windows 10 with Docker Desktop 4.2.0 using the WSL2 backend
- A WSL2 distro running Ubuntu 20.04
- In WSL2, I have `ssh-agent` running and aware of my key:

  ```
  λ ssh-add -l
  4096 SHA256:wDqVYQshQBCG/Sri/bsgjEaUFboQDUO/9FJqhFMncdk /home/taschan/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
  ```

The docs say

> the extension will automatically forward your local SSH agent if one is running

But if I do `ssh-add -l` in the devcontainer, it responds with `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`; and of course starting one (with `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`) only starts one that doesn't know of my private key.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11):

I had basically the same issue.  Running Windows 11 with WSL2 and my VSCode Devcontainer wouldn't show any ssh keys (running `ssh-add -l` inside the container showed an empty list) despite having Git configured on my host machine with working ssh keys.

For me, there were 3 separate instances of `ssh-agent` on my machine:

- WSL2
- Git Bash
- Windows host  *This is the one VSCode is forwarding to the devcontainer*

My existing ssh keys were set up inside Git Bash ([as per Github's instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)) so running `ssh-add -l` only ever showed my ssh keys from inside a Git Bash terminal, nowhere else.

However, as explained in the previous answer, digging through the Devcontainer startup logs shows that VSCode is forwarding only the host machine's `ssh-agent`, it doesn't look at the WSL2 or Git Bash ones.

**Solution:** I suggest following the below Microsoft docs page.  You need to enable an "Optional Feature" in Windows, then run a few commands in PowerShell (as admin) to activate the `ssh-agent` service.  With this set up, the `ssh-agent`/`ssh-add` commands will work from a regular CMD terminal too.
You can use these with the usual keygen commands etc to generate and add new keys on the host (I just `ssh-add`'ed the same keys generated by Git Bash originally).  The added keys should immediately be detected by `ssh-add -l` inside the container.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement

Comment: This is the solution I spent 3 hours looking for!!!!!!! TY

Answer (score 9):

Another way to share credentials is by mounting your SSH directory in `devcontainer.json`, in addition to your main code directory. Like so:

```
  "mounts": [
    "type=bind,source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/work",
    "type=bind,source=/home/${localEnv:USER}/.ssh,target=/root/.ssh,readonly"
  ]
```

Note that then you also do not need `workspaceMount` field.

More info:
https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/add-local-file-mount
https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: this would be nice..but assumes there is some variable USER set on the host...

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue I've added the following lines to the `devcontain.json` file:

```bash
"mounts": [
    "type=bind,source=${localEnv:HOME}/.ssh,target=/root/.ssh,readonly",
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had quite a lot of trouble to get this to work. The following steps might help troubleshooting:

1. Check that `ssh-agent` is running on your host and the key is added

   Run `ssh-agent -l` on Windows and expect to see the name of your key
2. Check that VSCode forwards the socket

   Search `ssh-agent` in the startup log. I had the message

   ```
   ssh-agent: SSH_AUTH_SOCK in container (/tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-a56c4b60c939c778f2998dee2a6bbe12285db2ad.sock) forwarded to local host (\\.\pipe\openssh-ssh-agent).
   ```

So it seems that VSCode is directly forwarding the Windows SSH agent here (and not an SSH agent running in your WSL).

Answer (score -1):

I tried many things but did not work. Finally after devcontainer is created , I note down the container name and copy the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub key inside container using docker cp command.

syntax:

```bash
docker cp <sourcefile> container_id:/dir
```

Copy both private and public key:

```bash
docker cp /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 eloquent_ritchie:/root/.ssh/
docker cp /root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub eloquent_ritchie:/root/.ssh/
```

change the permission of private key so that you can do git operations

```
docker exec eloquent_ritchie chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

`eloquent_ritchie` is sample container name. Your container name will differ. Use your container name

Then I was able to do Git operations inside devcontainer.

If you rebuild your container again you need to copy the file to devcontainer again.

Comment: Don't do that, this allows anyone with access to the container to use your ssh key